# What is applicationVariant.outputs?

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Android `build.gradle` directives often have parts like

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // do something to output
    }
}
```

The `variant.outputs` is puzzling. It seems to work, but the `outputs` property is neither visible [in the code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/8dca86a/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/ApplicationVariant.groovy) nor in [the plugin user guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Shrinking-Resources) or [the gradle index](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/index-all.html#_O_).

[How do I know the properties in applicationVariants of android gradle plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672469/how-do-i-know-the-properties-in-applicationvariants-of-android-gradle-plugin) asks about `ApplicationVariant` in general, but neither the question's nor the answer's links seems to contain the `outputs` property.

***Where is `outputs` specified/described?***

Comment: Did you check the Groovy documentation?

Comment: @cricket_007: good idea. I looked in gradle's https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskOutputs.html, https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput.html, https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html, but not at Groovy. Google for `groovy outputs` did not yield pointers, though. Any further ideas?

Comment: @cricket_007: [The index](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/index-all.html#_O_) did not seem to contain `outputs`. (there are several `out` and 1 `output`, though)

Comment: I don't actually know Groovy, I just know that's the language used for Gradle. I see that ApplicationVariants is an interface that doesn't extend anything, so I'm not sure what outputs is either

Comment: @cricket_007: It makes a lot of sense to look at Groovy.

Comment: I think `applicationVariants.all` is a function thing to a closure with a `variant` variable and **that** is what has `outputs`

Comment: @cricket_007: applicationVariants has an `all` method which applies a Closure, see https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/DomainObjectCollection.html. (seems pretty much like `map` in python, etc.) If so, `variant` is the variable name, which should be of type `ApplicationVariant`).

Comment: Seems to be what you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25999264/2308683

Comment: Example 18.10... https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html

Comment: The method. [`Task.getOutputs()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#getOutputs())

Comment: @cricket_007: thank you. That kind of solves it (even though it is still unclear why it is a `Task` (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html and https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html). Post an answer if you would like the upvote and accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be [BaseVariant.getOutputs()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/api/BaseVariant.java#90) and implement at BaseVariantImpl.

The code you check is probably at a very old version that `outputs` has not be added.