# "Android Gradle" Where can I find the definitions and/or codes of tons of variables in gradle files?

Tags: gradle, document

In Android development, we use gradle building system. We often see some usual codes in build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
```

We also see some unusual codes like:

```
javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["xxx": "xxx"]
            }
        }

applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        buildType = variant.buildType.name // Sets the current build type
    }
```

How do you know there's a `buildType` variable of `variant`? What's the object of `variant`? Can I see its details?

We often copy/paste those codes from internet without thinking too much, so we don't have a systematic knowledge of these declarations and variables.

I wonder if there is some documents and/or codes of such things? So that we can search like in a Javadoc, and write gradle files more freely, instead of just copy/paste.

I know there are two site:

> http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/index.html
>
> http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/javadoc/current/

But they don't clarify why there's the `variant.buildType` definition. You may find in the following class:

> http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/javadoc/current/com/android/build/api/variant/VariantInfo.html

there is a definition:

```
getBuildTypeName()
```

You may think `variant.buildType` is from this.

BUT. `getFlavorNames()` returns a list, while `variant.flavorName` is a string.

So, the above 2 documents are not enough, I believe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I know the properties in applicationVariants of android gradle plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672469/how-do-i-know-the-properties-in-applicationvariants-of-android-gradle-plugin)

Comment: @LukasKörfer I don't agree with the accepted answer of that post... as i said in my post, variant.flavorName is a string, while getFlavorNames() returns a list. So i think the java does not match the real code in build.gradle.

Comment: As you can see in the linked answer, `variant` is of type `ApplicationVariant`.

Comment: @LukasKörfer yes i've read that post. but i didn't find anything about the `flavorName` variable definition, or something looking like it?

Comment: Take a look at the second answer. It links the code of the interface `ApplicationVariant` and the two interfaces it extends from. The interface `BaseVariant` defines a method `getFlavorName()`, which can be accessed via `flavorName` in Groovy.

Comment: @LukasKörfer yes i've seen that. many thanks. is there any javadoc for the API?